# input textbox larger than input-lg

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-form

I am trying to increase the size of my search textbox to something larger than `input-lg` (using Bootstrap 3). Is that possible? Couldn't find much in Bootstrap 3 docs or SO posts.

Comment: You need to add your custom css, or you can add a col- class to your input element if the element needs to follow the grid

Comment: @gianni Thanks - I used custom css.

Comment: Great! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following. Thanks to @gianni's comment.

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control input-lg searchbox" name="query" type="text"  autocomplete="off">
```

**CSS**

```
.searchbox {
  font-size: 23px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1px 7px; 
  text-transform: capitalize; /* Capitalises first letter of each word only 'visually', value sent is as-typed */
}
```